# TERM environment variable not set in Thonny

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to use os.system('clear') in Thonny, but it keeps on giving me the TERM environment variable not set. I know that there is an easy way to fix this, but I can't figure out how to do this in Thonny.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact issue as a new Thonny user.

1. Switch Thonny over to Regular UI mode if not already there, Thonny will need a restart to pick up the change. It defaults to Simple mode on Raspberry Pi Bullseye.
2. In a terminal window `echo $TERM`. My result was `xterm-256color`.
3. In Thonny, go to Tools> Options. In the Environment Variables box, enter `TERM=<echo result>` on its own line. In my case this was `TERM=xterm-256color`. You'll need to restart Thonny again to pick this up.
4. Run your code. The error will disappear.

I know this is an old thread, but it came up in the top search results when I was looking to solve this exact issue so I'm hoping this helps someone else.